# iam new finding an error in java

Tags: java

```
package ooptutorial;

public class ShoppingTest {
    //name of file must be same as name of method

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shopping firstClient = new Shopping();
        int[] pricelist = {299,399,499};
        for (int i = 0; i < pricelist.length; i++){
            firstClient.Basket(pricelist[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("The Total Price of your Item is : "
            + firstClient.r);
        System.out.println("The Total Price with VAT : "
            + firstClient.TotalPrice());
        firstClient.DailyIncome(firstClient.TotalPrice());

        Shopping secondClient = new Shopping();
        int[] pricelist2 = {599,159,459};
        for(int i = 0; pricelist2.length; i++){
            secondClient.Basket(pricelist2[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("The Total Price of your Item is : "
            + secondClient.r);
        System.out.println("The Total Price with VAT : "
            + secondClient.TotalPrice());
        secondClent.DailyIncome(secondClient.TotalPrice());    
        System.out.println("The Daily Income : "
            + secondClient._dailyIncome);
    }
}
```

[ed: artificial break added]

```
class Shopping{
    int r = 0;
    final int VAT_VALUE = 17;
    static int DailyIncome = 0;

    int Basket(int ItemPrice){
        r = ItemPrice;
        return r;
    }

    int TotalPrice(){
        return ((r * VAT_VALUE) / 100) + r;
    }

    public static int DailyIncome(int income){
        _dailyIncome += income;
        return _dailyIncome;
    }
}
```

Comment: first you can try formatting that :)

Comment: and second, ask a question :)

Comment: Uf da.  http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You have an error on this line:

```
for(int i = 0; pricelist2.length; i++){
```

Because `pricelist2.length` is an `int`, not a `boolean` as required by Java syntax.  Perhaps you meant:

```
for(int i = 0; i < pricelist2.length; i++){
```